# How do I enforce parent-child struct lifetime?

Tags: rust

I'm writing wrapper code for an external C library, and I'm trying to convince the Rust compiler to enforce external lifetime restrictions that are not reflected in the Rust code itself. For example, one type of "opaque handle" can return a child handle that is only valid for the lifetime of the parent handle.

I experimented with `std::marker::PhantomData`, but I couldn't convince the compiler to return the expected error.

In other words, I'd like the following block of code fail to compile:

```
struct Parent;

struct Child; // Note that there is no reference to the parent struct

impl Parent {
    fn get_child( &self ) -> Child {
        Child
    }
}

// I'd like this to complain with "p does not live long enough"
fn test() -> Child {
    let p = Parent;
    p.get_child()
}

fn main() {
    let c = test();
}
```

Comment: I assume there is some reason you don't want to go ahead and add a reference to the `Parent` in the `Child`?

Answer (score 13):

You had the right idea with `PhantomData`. You add a lifetime parameter and a `PhantomData` field to `Child`. The `PhantomData` generic parameter is what you want to emulate in the struct. In this case you want `Child` to act as if it contains a `&Parent`.

```
struct Child<'a> {
    parent: PhantomData<&'a Parent>,
}

impl Parent {
    fn get_child<'a>(&'a self) -> Child<'a> {
        Child {
            parent: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to modify the `test` function to have a generic argument, otherwise you don't see your requested `doesn't live long enough` error,
because the `Child needs a lifetime` error occurs first.

```
fn test<'a>() -> Child<'a> {
    let p = Parent;
    p.get_child()
}
```

[Try it out in the Playground](http://is.gd/LiWGl6)